# runtime error '5' when using Autofilter to delete visible rows with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, runtime

When I run the following code (Which is designed to filter a table and then delete the rows that are filtered) I receive a runtime error '5'. This error doesn't appear when I step through the macro. Only when running it.

```
Sub delete()
    Rng.AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:=Array( _
    "ROCKFORD DSC", "MATTESON PLANT", "WHEELING PLANT"), _
     Operator:=xlFilterValues

     Rng.Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of `Rng` ? Can you paste a screenshot of your data set?

Comment: @eyanosa , what if you add a space here ? `"ROCKFORD DSC", "MATTESON PLANT", "WHEELING PLANT"), _` (after the coma)

Comment: The value of `Rng` is:

    `Dim Rng As Range
    Set Rng = Range("A1").CurrentRegion`

The space after the comma is in my code. That was a mistake when I posted the code here.